# Issues in reading .grd file using R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a .grd file on rainfall data (sharing the file link below). It is a Geosoft grid format file. The following error I encountered when I tried to read that using 'raster' package. I know that 'raster'reads its own format of .grd files. But I have no clue about what to do. I found some r-help page where they talk about converting into a different format (like .flt) and then use it. This file encountered error in doing so using Montage viewer.

```
> require(raster)
Loading required package: raster
Loading required package: sp

> x<-raster("rf_1984.grd")
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  `C:\Users\Soumen Dey\Desktop\rf_1984.grd' not recognised as a supported file format.

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

Can anybody can give any suggestions regarding this and help me reading this file using R ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Mnscd1GGfkd2JkNzk4ODE0ZEE/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for your time.

P.S I know Somebody who have successfully used it in MATLAB.

Comment: You could try using the `gdal` library via the `rgdal` R package.

Comment: Any specific function ? readGDAL and creat2GDAL did not work. The error message says it is unsupported file format.

Comment: Be sure that the version of `gdal` you have installed has support for .grd files. The [master list](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) seems to suggest that for some .grd file format there is support. I'm not sure your version supports this .grd and if that .grd is the .grd you are dealing with. Type `gdalinfo --formats` on the command line to check which formats your version supports.

Comment: For reference, question also asked on r-sig-geo mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2015-November/023691.html

Comment: If you can, please provide the original source of the dataset.

Comment: @Pascal, Pardon me. I can not provide the original source of the data as I got it from a professor.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra . Neither 'gdalinfo' in GDAL nor 'GDALinfo' in R (using package 'rgdal') seems to support the format of this .grd data file. Now I am more confused about the actual format of the file and what to do so that R can read the file.

Comment: @Kush Were you able to read in the file in R??

Comment: @Deepak. No. I couldn't. I was in a hurry and used MATLAB instead.